# Can't connect a second screen

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, dell

I'm on ubuntu 18.04.3 with kernel version 4.15.0.45.48 on the Dell Inspiron 7591 2n1.

When i try to connect a second screen on the hdmi port, there is no signal send to the screen.

I tried to install the drivers nvidia but id doesn't resolve my problems.

When I try to find my GPU with "lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0950
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor    Thermal Subsystem
--
3c:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1d13 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0950
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

But when I find my computer on the Dell plateform with the service tag it shows ma that there is a  NVIDIA GeForce MX250 mit 2-GB-GDDR5-Grafikspeicher inside.

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: on 16.04: System settings > Displays > turn ON all displays you wish to use. (18.x system settings differ in layout)

Comment: I would start with updating your system by `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: And also there may be Fn+Fx key to enable a second monitor.

Comment: @Hannu when I go to display I have "Unknow Display" in the top so exept manage my orientation, resolution and scale i can't do nothing.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did the update and upgrade, nothing new. I also try Fn+Fx nothing appears

Comment: I believe you need to specify exactly what `I tried to install the drivers nvidia` means. Exactly which driver did you try? You have TWO GPUs, if I'm not too far off you need to tell which to use... but I'm out on a limb; I have no experience with this kind of setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing the Windows key (Meta/Super) + P. It brings up a few display options such as Mirroring, Extend Left/Right, etc. I do this each time I connect a display to my system for the external monitor to get it to work.

Note: This shortcut may vary depending on distribution. I use Kubuntu 19.10.